# Safety Spot location map for testing NMASafetySpotWarnerDelegate class

Tags: here-api

To test a class with NMASafetySpotWarnerDelegate protocol I need locations off Safety Spots (NMASafetySpot), to setup a equivalent rout for Turn-By-Turn navigation. 
As well i search locations where realistic views (NMANavigationManagerDelegate) are supported.

Exist a HERE map with this type of information? 
How can I test the callbacks for safety spots and realistic views?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at the [coverage information in the user guide](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-hybrid-plus/topics/safety-camera-coverage.html) to get an idea of the number of safety spots present in each country. Also, you can make the safety spots visible on the `NMAMapView` to look for them using the `safetySpotsVisible` property.

For Realistic View, this feature is dependent on having proper lane and junction information which should be widely available in HERE map data. You can get an overview of which countries have high quality navigation data [here](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile/common/map_data_releases/topics/navigable-countries.html). Note that in order to turn on Relistic View you must set the `realisticViewMode` and `realisticViewAspectRatios` properties of the `NMANavigationManager`

Comment: Great information. Your answer clear all my topics.
Thanks